# Is distance from a point to a subspace of finite normed linear space is attained?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let X be a finite dimensional normed linear space and M be a subspace of X .Now we know that x be a  vector then there exist m such that d(x,M)=||x-m||.

Now my question is if x is a unit vector then can we choose m such that ||m||<=1 and d(x,M)=||x-m||?

Geometrically i checked it in R² with usual norm it seems like that it is true.But in general case i did not conclude anything.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hope going to be closed soon unless you edit to include your effort.

Comment: @LostinSpace i edited it.I forgot to add it .

Comment: This is not true in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Ruy now look over the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true.

Take $X = \mathbb R^2$ with norm $\|x\| = \max(|x_1|, |x_2|)$ ($l_\infty$ norm).

Take $x = (1, 1)$ and $M = \{(t, 3 \cdot t)| t \in \mathbb R\}$.

[image: plot]

Green line is $M$, points inside red square have norm $1$ or less, points inside blue square have distance to $x$ of $1/2$ or less.

It's easy to see that $d(x, M) = d((1, 1), (1/2, 3/2)) = 1/2$, but all points with at most unit norm in $M$ have distance to $x$ more than $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,But this result later i saw with one of my senior that this is true in hilbert space.So it is also true in any finite dimensional hilbert space.
I will include the answer.

Let, H be a hilbert space and if x is a unit vector then there exist a vector m in M such that d(x,M)=||x-m|| ,where M is a closed linear subspace.
Now we know that x-m is orthogonal to M.Now by cauchy Schwartz inequality ||m||²=<x,m><=||x||.||m|| ,now if m≠0 then ||m||<=||x||=1 ,and if m=0 then also ||m||<=1. Hence proved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).